# How to remove discontinuity from the equation?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, continuity

I have a function $f$, which have two cases:

$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{ \sin(a + bx) - \sin(a) }{b} &\mbox{if } b \neq 0\\
x \cos(a) &\mbox{if } b = 0
\end{cases}
$$

The first part has a discontinuity at $b=0$ because the denominator, that is why the second case is needed.

Is it possible to rearrange the equation in a way, that we do not need cases, only one closed formula? I would like to avoid dividing by near to zero values, because of floating point arithmetic.

---

**What I've tried:**

$$
\frac{ \sin(a + bx) - \sin(a) }{b} =
\frac{ \sin(a) \cos(bx) + \cos(a) \sin(bx) - \sin(a) }{b}
$$

I have no idea how to progress any further

Comment: This is not a discontinuity, it's an indeterminacy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{mysinc}{\mathop{\rm sinc}}$
You can use the [$\mysinc$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) function. It is already implemented in some languages, for example see the [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sinc.html) version.

$$\begin{align}\frac{\sin a \cos bx+\cos a \sin bx-\sin a}{b}&=\sin a\frac{\cos bx -1}{b}+\cos a\frac{\sin bx}{b}\\&=\sin a\frac{-2\sin^2\frac{bx}{2}}{b}+x\cos a\mysinc bx\\&=-x\sin a \sin\frac{bx}{2} \mysinc\frac{bx}{2}+x\cos a\mysinc bx  \end{align}\\$$

When $b=0$ the first term vanishes because of the $\sin$, and the second becomes $x\cos a$ since $\mysinc 0=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a special function such as the Cardinal Sine ($\text{sinc}$, see Andrei's answer) which will absorb the indeterminacy, the answer is negative.

This function has a simple Taylor's development, but this is unsuitable for your purpose if you want to avoid a piecewise definition by all means.

Answer (score 0):

Remember for continuity at $p,$

$$\lim_{y\to p}f(y)=f(p)$$

Now using [Prosthaphaeresis Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) and $\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\sin h}h=1$

$$\lim_{b\to0}\dfrac{\sin(a+bx)-\sin a}b=x\lim_{b\to0}\dfrac{\sin\dfrac{bx}2}{\dfrac{bx}2}\lim_{b\to0}\cos\left(a+\dfrac{bx}2\right)=x\cos a=f(0)$$

So. $f(x)$ is continuous at $b=0$

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @MarkViola, Please find the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align} 
f(x)&=\int_0^x \cos(a+bt)\,dt
\end{align}